# "On the ground" vs "in the field"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-choice

If I want to say that it's not the same to treat a patient in the hospital as to treat him outside of the hospital, then which phrase is more appropriate?

Option 1:

> "It's not the same to treat a patient in a hospital as to treat a
>   patient **in the field**."

Option 2:

> "It's not the same to treat a patient in a hospital as to treat a
>   patient **on the ground**"

Comment: Have you tried an internet search to see which one might be more common?

Comment: It is a specific context which I didn't find on Google.

Comment: *In the field* is frequently shorthand for *in the field of battle*, while *on the ground* generally refers to the place where events are taking place as opposed to the cities where politicians and journalists are talking about them. It's hard to know from your sentences whether either is more appropriate.

Comment: If your intent is to state that the patient is being treated at or near the location of the injury, then "in the field" is the right choice.  I'm struggling to think of a good situation where I would use the second sentence.  It's not exactly incorrect, it's just that the idiom doesn't exactly fit with medical practice in my mind.

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw both of them as translation to the word/term in my native language. The context is medical, to treat a victim outside of the hospital, in the place where the ambulance comes to treat the patient.

Comment: I think it is difficult to say without more context. Also, why do you want to say this differently? In a general sense, "in the hospital" and "outside of the hospital" are fine.

Comment: Right, but outside of the hospital can be in clinic also for example. In addition I wanted to mention the area of the event, when the injury occurred. If you want more focused example, then I can say for example: "In practice it's more difficult to treat the patient "in the field" than in the hospital, because in the field you don't have the necessary things that you have in the hospital". I can use also examples from other fields, rather than medicine: "We indeed study tricks to catch thieves, but in practice, in the field it's more difficult to catch them than you think".

Answer (score 2):

> [**In the field**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-field): (phrase) Work or study that is done in the field is done in a real, natural environment rather than in a theoretical way or in controlled conditions. (Collins English Dictionary)

In your example, "in the field" seems more appropriate.  The idiomatic expression "on the ground" is not used this way, and I'm not certain what it would mean in this context.

Comment: It's also worth noting that *in the field* can apply to more situations than *on the ground*